# How do I install bidet T-valve here?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

[image: toilet in question]

How do I install a bidet T-valve here?

I’m trying to install a handheld bidet on the toilet. This is the one I’d like to install

[image]

Unlike other toilets, there isn’t much space to install the T-valve. Any ideas on what I can do here? How do i make more space for the T-valve there, is there some extension pipe that I can get?

The pipe in the pic reads 7/8” ballcock, 3/8” comp, 12” length

Answer (score 1):

Yes you buy the [7/8 ballcock extension hose](https://www.amazon.ca/Stainless-Extension-Handheld-Quality-Braided/dp/B08N335VPN).

[image: ballcock extension hose]

Comment: I would think this would normally be called a "pipe" or "hose", not a "cord"... Usually "cord" is for electricity or trussing up your prisoner, not running water through. ;)